# How can I tell if a YouTube video from the users private feed is public or not?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, gdata, gdata-api

I'mm using gdata to retreive videos, but it's giving me all the users videos and I just want the public ones.

```
client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
feed_url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/someusername/uploads'
client.ClientLogin('somelogin', 'somepassword')

feed = client.GetYouTubeVideoFeed(feed_url)
```

Gives me all videos and there doesn't seem to be anything in the feed indicating if a video is public or not.

Answer (score 0):

If can't find the Service Method in the `gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()` lists that exists the `GetYouTubePublicVideoFeed()` method, you will filter out the public videos by yourself.

Comment: You probably want to edit the tone of your message for a more professional setting.